# PHP Overloading similar to sprintf()?

Tags: php

How do you write a function in PHP that can accept an *unlimited*  number of arguments similar to sprintf?

```
sprintf("one:%s",$one);
sprintf("one:%s two:%s",$one,$two);
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`func_get_args()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Example from php.net

```
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily. Declare your function with the static arguments

```
function myprintf ($string)
```

and get hold of the unlimited additional arguments using [**func_get_args()**](http://www.php.net/func_get_args).

Answer (score 1):

A function can accept as many parameters as you want ; it just has to deal with them using the following functions : [`func_num_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php), [`func_get_arg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php), and [`func_get_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

Examples are given on those three manual pages, but here's the one from the `func_get_args` page *(quoting)* :

```
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

And the output will be :

```
Number of arguments: 3<br />
Second argument is: 2<br />
Argument 0 is: 1<br />
Argument 1 is: 2<br />
Argument 2 is: 3<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`func_get_args()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).